# How do i support only landscape version for ios 6.0 in phonegap application?

Tags: cordova, ios6, xcode4.5, uiinterfaceorientation

Checked with so many asked questions about this but nothing has worked for my case.So i needed to ask it again.

I am building app with phone-gap framework.Upto ios 5 it's running fine but as the case with ios 6.0 those methods are not supported so i replaced them with:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

in my MainViewController.m file.

I need my entire app in only landscape left and landscape right.

In my plist file i have mentioned landscape left and right for both iphone and ipad.

Any idea would be of great help.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution.This problem occurs because the MainViewController is not set to be the rootViewController in AppDelegate.m.
In your AppDelegate.m replace:

```
[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
```

with

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

Then it behaves properly for my app running on ios 6.0

Answer (score 0):

For IOS

In config.xml set:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape"></preference>
```

or

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait"></preference>
```

In "ProjectName"-info.plist file in ios folder under resources folder for "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" set:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

or

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

or

for portrait orientation:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
```

or

```
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
```

Include which is applicable for your requirements.